# Removing Multiple Activities from History After a Certain Point

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I would like to be able to remove activities from history but only after a certain threshold has been reached. The structure of my application goes like this:

```
Home --> User Input  --> User Input --> User Input --> Posting in DB
```

I would like to make it so that while the user is giving data in the input pages, they can easily go back and make a change if necessary, but once they have created a database entry they should not be able to move backwards throughout the forms in previous activities, but instead selecting back should take them straight to "Home".

I am aware of the `finish()` as well as `android:noHistory="true"` methods but these doesn't really work for delaying the history removal until later. Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the below code, it removes all activities from history, and starts home activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Welcome.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I don't necessarily want the user to be unable to press the back button, simply if they do press it they should not be able to go back to the input pages, rather go directly to the "Home" page. Couldn't I use the method you've provided and make it so if they press back from the activity after finishing all the forms, it sends them straight to the home activity?

Comment: Yes, you can. But I'd suggest using onBackPressed instead onKeyDown, since onBackPressed also catches the 'up' navigation when the user taps the home icon in the toolbar. In onBackPressed, decide if the user should be able to go back. If so, invoke super.onBackPressed(), if not, use an Intent with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to navigate to the 'Home' activity as @sedpol shows.

Comment: As @GreyBeardedGeek said, onBackPressed() is better solution. I updated the answer.